# django crispy forms and bootstrap5 floating labels

Tags: django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I could use some help.  I'm trying to use floating labels in a form.  It works fine if I hand-code the html.  But when I move it to crispy, I lose the floating behavior of the label and the label moves above the input field.  Here's a snippet of the crispy code:

```
Div(
    Div(
        Field('first_name',
              css_class='form-control'),
        css_class='form-floating'),
    css_class="col-md",                
),
```

and here's the resulting html:

```
<div class="col-md" > 
  <div class="form-floating" > 
    <div id="div_id_first_name" class="mb-3"> 
      <label for="id_first_name" class="form-label requiredField">
         First name<span class="asteriskField">*</span> 
      </label> 
      <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" class="form-control textinput textInput" required id="id_first_name">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Through experimentation, I've figured out the problem is with `<div id="div_id_first_name" class="mb-3">` .  If this `div` is eliminated, the floating behavior returns.

My question: what's the best way to solve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crispy-bootstrap5 template pack comes with a new layout object for floating fields. You can use this in place of divs with the bootstrap
foating class.

```
from crispy_bootstrap5.bootstrap5 import FloatingField

# then in your Layout
... Layout(
    FloatingField("first_name"),
)
```

https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/crispy-bootstrap5#whats-new

Comment: This worked perfectly (and simplified the layout).  Thank you so much for the help.